# PIL ImageDraw.Draw() does not draw the line at all

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i have this function:

```
def check(user, number):
    for cartella in all_:
        if number in cartella:
            imgg = Image.open("layout {}.png".format(user))
            drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(imgg)
            drawer.line(coords[cartella.index(number)], fill=128, width=5)
            imgg.show()
```

which should draw a black line on the image at given coordinates, but it doesn't; i checked with

```
print(coords[cartella.index(number)])
```

and the coordinates gets recieved correctly by the function, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `fill = (128, 128, 128)`. BTW, it draws gray line, to draw black you need `(0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Can you show us what `print(coords[cartella.index(number)])` prints out?

Comment: i'm just stupid, you need a 4 point tuple to draw a line the coords dict has 2 points tuples, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the value of the fill parameter a tuple. For example (0, 0, 0)

```
drawer.line(coords[cartella.index(number)], fill=(0, 0, 0), width=5)
```

Comment: i'm just stupid, you need a 4 point tuple to draw a line the coords dict has 2 points tuples, sorry for the inconvenience